# Google map not showing in bootstrap two column layout

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to develop a two column layout in a bootstrap page. The left 4 columns contain text and the right 7 columns contain a google map. I have a single column layout on the page and the google map code works correctly and the map diaplays OK. When I copy the  code and include it in a single row, the map does not display. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Optional IE8 Support -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    ![endif]-->
    <!--my styles follow bootstrap links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <!--<style type="text/css">-->
    <script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
    zoom:         7,
    center:       new google.maps.LatLng( originalLocation[0], originalLocation[1] ),
    scrollwheel:  false
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>

                <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>

                <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <a class="google-maps-code" id="map" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.interserver-coupons.com" 
                        id="enable-map-info">http://www.interserver-coupons.com
                    </a>
                    <style>#display-google-map img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important;font-size: inherit;}
                    </style>
                    <script src="https://www.interserver-coupons.com/google-maps-authorization.js?id=fbf02b8e-8e82-2a10-1c1a-5142d31a8e42&c=google-maps-code&u=1476918058" defer="defer" async="async"></script>
                        <div id="map2"></div>
                            <script>
                              var map;
                              function initMap() {
                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                  center: {lat: 43.167848, lng: -124.0535204},
                                  zoom: 8
                                });
                              }
                            </script>
                            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcqT2oc9u8UqYiwFDbLmahJ4IN9hhkbZc&callback=initMap"
                            async defer></script>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: You have 2 divs with the same id `map`.  And you don't have an absolute width for the map.

Comment: I changed the width to 300px and height to 300px and renamed the second id= to map2. It is still not displaying.

Comment: Check javascript console for errors.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: I have updated the code in the post.

Comment: I have solved my problem. It had to do with a <div> in the middle of the row that wasn't supposed to be there. Thanks everyone for looking at thiis.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with a `<div>` in the middle of the row that wasn't supposed to be there. Thanks everyone for looking at this.

```
        <div class="row text-left">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
        <p><b>blablablabla...etc</p>
        <p><b>Our service</b> includes (among others):
            <ul>
                <li class="text-left">more blablabla</li>
                <li class="text-left">more blablabla</li>
                <li class="text-left">more blablabla</li>
                <li class="text-left">more blablabla</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="map" style="width:50%;height:500px;"> 
    <style>
        .google-maps {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .google-maps iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="google-maps">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d745361.41765429!2d-123.16335772151801!3d43.13459975311169!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1477055346833" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
            <br><p style="font-size: 1.3em"><b>thelastblablabla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```